# Automatic shutdown after startup

Tags: linux-mint, shutdown

I played a little with the shutdown command typing:

```
sudo shutdown +20
```

and then:

```
sudo shutdown -c
```

I then manually hibernate my pc because I had to go out. Now I'm back and I found that I could no longer turn on the pc because once Linux is started, I can see the desktop for 1 second, and then my pc shutdown.

How can I solve this?

Comment: When you turn the PC back on, does it boot normally or *does it un-hibernate?* (I have never used hibernation in Linux so am not sure exactly how you'd tell, but I assume it's pretty obvious.) Does it *keep turning off on subsequent attempts?* (I assume it does, but best to be sure.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try adding `noacpi` to kernel-/linux-line via grub on boot.

1. Start PC
2. Select First Entry in Grub
3. Press `e`
4. Append `noacpi` to kernel-/linux-line
5. Press F10 if you have grub2 (for grub i don't know...maybe just press enter)

This way you should get back in your system and be able check out whats going wrong.

Comment: You could also try adding `single` to bring up the system in single-user mode.

Comment: Note that `noacpi` probably won't prevent the system shutdown sequence, but it *will* keep the computer from powering off. It might also be a good idea to remove `quiet` from the kernel command line, if that parameter is present: it'll give you a lot more information about what happens during the boot process.